# CupertinoDatePicker using internationalization

Tags: flutter, datepicker, localization, internationalization

I am fairly new to Fllutter.  I am using Localization to define the app language in multiple countries.  The App works in English without issues.  If We change language Texts are correctly translated.  But if we change the device language.  My CupertinoDatePicker dates fails.  Here is an example using Spanish as language.  The error message reads "The method datePickerDayOfMonth was called on null".  Here is a code sample:

```
                    Container(
                        margin: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0),
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *.65,
                      child:
                        CupertinoTheme(
                          data: CupertinoThemeData(
                            textTheme: CupertinoTextThemeData(
                              dateTimePickerTextStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          child:
                          CupertinoDatePicker(
                            minimumDate: DateTime.now(),
                            mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
                            initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
                            onDateTimeChanged: (dateTime) {
                              setState(() {
                                _followUpDate = dateTime;
                              });
                            },
                          )
                      )
                    )
                  ]
              )
            )
          )
```

Here is the device screen results:

[image: Cupertino Date Pickers]

Hope you may be able to help me.  Look forward to hearing for solutions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try to add this in your main

```
localizationsDelegates: [
            GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,

          ],
```

Comment: YES!  Thank you so much.  Adding your suggestion fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks it's really useful.